# hacer en if ternario

Tags: javascript

la consigna es la siguiente:

Vamos a poner en práctica el if ternario. En este escenario vamos a contar con dos bicicletas y nos interesa saber cuál tiene el rodado más grande.
Para esto, a la variable marcaRodadoMasGrande debemos asignarle la marca de la bicicleta (como string) utilizando un operador ternario. El operador ternario debe comparar los rodados de ambas bicicletas y retornar el nombre de la marca que tenga el mayor rodado.
Las marcas esperadas son los strings: "Mountain Bike" o "Aurora"

el codigo es el siguiente

```
let rodadoMountainBike = 18;
let rodadoAurora = 24;
let marcaRodadoMasGrande = ???;
console.log("La bicicleta con  mayor rodado es la " + marcaRodadoMasGrande);
```

a lo cual yo intento haciendo lo siguiente

```
let rodadoMountainBike = 18;

let rodadoAurora = 24;

let marcaRodadoMasGrande = "marca" ? "Aurora" : "Mountain Bike";
console.log("La bicicleta con  mayor rodado es la " + marcaRodadoMasGrande);
```

creo que muy bien no entendí como hacer el if ternario porque creo no estar comparando, ya que bien no se cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Funciona así: `(Condicion) ? (Valor si la condicion se cumple) : (Valor si la condicion no se cumple)`

Comment: Lo que va antes del "?" debe ser una condición por ej: 
let marcaRodadoMasGrande = rodadoMountainBike  <  rodadoAurora ? "Aurora" : "Mountain Bike"